# Pylint check in `src` directory not finding errors in `src/collect/` directory

Tags: python, pylint

When I run the command `pylint src` in my project, I expect it to go through all of the folders and files within `src` and find the errors. However, I run it and get:

```
(.venv) kasparpoland@kasparMac server % pylint src

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

However, when I run `pylint src/collect`, I get hundreds of errors:

```
(.venv) kasparpoland@kasparMac server % pylint src/collect
************* Module src.collect.collect
src/collect/collect.py:36:0: C0301: Line too long (147/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:72:0: C0301: Line too long (126/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:81:0: C0301: Line too long (107/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:105:0: C0301: Line too long (104/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:116:0: C0301: Line too long (146/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:127:0: C0301: Line too long (155/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:161:0: C0301: Line too long (140/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:177:0: C0301: Line too long (108/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:200:0: C0301: Line too long (110/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:233:0: C0301: Line too long (132/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:236:0: C0301: Line too long (101/100) (line-too-long)
src/collect/collect.py:258:0: C0301: Line too long (108/100) (line-too-long)
... AND MANY MORE
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have an ``__init__.py`` at the root of src ?

Comment: Yes, I do. though I realized a command like `pylint *.py **/*.py` works and finds every python file in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pylint` command only searches the immediate directory, or python files within it. A command like `pylint *.py **/*.py` will search recursively for python files, beginning at the root.